# TSQL - Updating a column value with ORDER BY till a certain column value is found

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-query-store

I have this table:

```
ID - Uniqueidentifier
TYPEDUT_ID - Uniqueidentifer
OPERATION - Integer
ACTIVE - Integer (0/1)
CREATED - DateTime
```

I want to sort the rows `ORDER BY CREATED DESC` and update `ACTIVE = 0` from the top to bottom till I reach a certain OPERATION.

Sample data:

```
            ID                                     TYPEDUT_ID                 OPERATION        ACTIVE             CREATED
ADFFC7CB-C938-448B-BF15-019C31434AFD    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    2000             1         2016-09-06 13:06:29.333
CF7E2375-EC6E-416F-99E6-15213BD829D8    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    3000             1         2016-09-06 13:01:47.657
31189043-8B7E-4DCC-8EAC-62AD5EDB32E2    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    2000             1         2016-09-06 13:10:07.720
E473B887-65DB-40FA-94D9-697F20E787B9    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    2300             1         2016-09-06 13:30:41.227
1DD2C120-7859-4868-9C71-83F6BC3F7488    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    3100             1         2016-09-06 14:40:46.087
B27283A8-43DD-468E-95CB-99DD1BC95321    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    2100             1         2016-09-06 13:23:34.883
103899E9-33B1-4FCA-AA1B-A51040B35FBD    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    2400             1         2016-09-06 14:03:21.830
```

Now if I put 3000 as my desired OPERATION the expected result should look like this:

```
                   ID                              TYPEDUT_ID                 OPERATION  ACTIVE           CREATED
1DD2C120-7859-4868-9C71-83F6BC3F7488    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    3100       0       2016-09-06 14:40:46.087
103899E9-33B1-4FCA-AA1B-A51040B35FBD    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    2400       0       2016-09-06 14:03:21.830
E473B887-65DB-40FA-94D9-697F20E787B9    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    2300       0       2016-09-06 13:30:41.227
B27283A8-43DD-468E-95CB-99DD1BC95321    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    2100       0       2016-09-06 13:23:34.883
31189043-8B7E-4DCC-8EAC-62AD5EDB32E2    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    2000       0       2016-09-06 13:10:07.720
ADFFC7CB-C938-448B-BF15-019C31434AFD    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    2000       0       2016-09-06 13:06:29.333
CF7E2375-EC6E-416F-99E6-15213BD829D8    CC055EBE-2655-4B2F-B6C2-BF9BCE46941B    3000       1       2016-09-06 13:01:47.657
```

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh edited! Please take a look and try to give a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can get the minimum created time for a particular operation using a subquery. You can then use that information to define the rows to be updated:

```
update t
    set active = 0
    where created <= (select min(t2.created)
                      from t t2
                      where operation = @Operation
                     );
```

EDIT:

Apparently, I understand backwards.  The solution is the other way:

```
update t
    set active = 0
    where created >= (select max(t2.created)
                      from t t2
                      where operation = @Operation
                     );
```

Comment: Dude it didn't work. Take a look at the edits. I added a few sample data. Say if the desired operation is 3000/2000, I want to sort the data by date DESC and then making ACTIVE =0 till I reach 3000/2000.

Comment: I think Gordon just got it the wrong way round - change <= to > and min to max

Comment: @JamesCasey Excellent! It worked like a charm!! Thanks a ton man :D

Comment: @TarekSaazeb . . . I'm curious.  Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: @GordonLinoff accepted it again. Sorry it was a miss-click.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to sort the data based on the descending order of Created. I have used a temporary table which stores the sorted data.

```
 DECLARE @tempTable1 TABLE(Temp_Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),Id NVARCHAR(MAX),TYPEDUT_ID  NVARCHAR(MAX),OPERATION INT,ACTIVE INT,CREATED DATETIME)

    DECLARE @operation INT =3000
    INSERT INTO  @tempTable1(Id,TYPEDUT_ID,OPERATION,ACTIVE,CREATED) SELECT Id,TYPEDUT_ID,OPERATION,ACTIVE,CREATED FROM Table_Name ORDER BY CREATED DESC

    UPDATE @tempTable1
    SET active = 0
    WHERE operation != @operation

    SELECT * FROM @tempTable1
```

Comment: that's okay but this solution won't work either. It will set ACTIVE=0 to every operation but the desired one. Which is not my intention. The process has to stop updating ACTIVE to 0 once it reaches the desired operation.